# iPhone web splash screen not working

Tags: iphone

In iPhone web applications you supposedly can define a custom splash screen that will appear while the site is loading (when loading the site from a saved bookmark icon on the home page).  The point is to make the web app startup experience feel a lot more like a real iphone application.

I believe the syntax is like this:

`<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/splash.png" />` (placed in the `<head>` section of the page).

Where splash.png is a vertically oriented 320x460 image.

I can't seem to get it work... does anybody have any tips and tricks for this?

Answer (score 8):

Make sure it is 320x460 pixels.

You already said that, but that was the solution for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can only set one splash screen or else it will fail. In order to select either an ipad or iphone splash screen you need a little javascript.

The ipad landscape splash screen that can be used for native apps doesn't work for web apps. Neither would a retina splash screen for the iphone4. You can only choose an ipad or an iphone sizes splash. Setting the size attribute on the link element seems to work on the ipad. But having more than one splash image link element makes the iphone fail.

The splash screen sizes must be exact. 320x460 for iphone/ipod and 1024x748 for ipad. If you need a landscape slash screen you'll need to rotate it in photoshop as there is no control during the app's relaunch.

To test it's best to try first with app cache off and throttle the bandwidth with charles proxy or something similar.

```
<!-- status bar -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

<!-- hide safari chrome -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

<!-- iphone start up screens -->
<script type="application/javascript">
    var appl = document.createElement("link");
    appl.setAttribute('rel', 'apple-touch-startup-image');
    if(screen.width < 321 && window.devicePixelRatio == 1) {
      appl.setAttribute('href', 'img/icons/launch320x460.png'); //iphone 3Gs or below
    } else if (screen.width < 321 && window.devicePixelRatio == 2) { 
      //setting @2x or a 640x920 image fails, just use the iphone splash screen
    } else if (screen.width < 769 && Math.abs(window.orientation) != 90) {
      appl.setAttribute('href', 'img/icons/launch1024x748.png'); //ipad 2 or below (portait)
    } else if (screen.width < 769 && Math.abs(window.orientation) == 90) { 
      //landscape fails as well, use standard ipad screen
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(appl);
</script>

<!-- iphone springboard icons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="57x57" href="img/icons/icon57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114" href="img/icons/icon114x114.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72" href="img/icons/icon72x72.png" />
```

Comment: I got this script working, but there seems to be a bug with the splash screens on the iPad. If I launch the web app in landscape the first time, neither of the splash screens are shown. If I launch in portrait the first time, that splash-screen works, but the landscape never works.

It seems I'm not the only one with this issue, see this thread over at the apple forum: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3316892?start=0&tstart=0

Can anyone confirm they have successfully created and displayed both landscape and portrait splash screens on iPad HTML5 web apps?

Answer (score 3):

Apple doesn't have much in the way of documentation on this topic (see [this URL](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002051-CH3-SW6)).

A couple of things to note:

- The code snippet you provided assumes your image is living at http://yourdomain.com/splash.png
- This only works for iPhone OS 3.0 and later
- The image must be a PNG
- The image is only displayed until the page's DOM is ready

You can also use the following code to explicitly set the web app icon:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all these links come after your other stylesheets in your header.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 4 does not show the splash screen if you have a notification bar at the top - e.g. when using the personal hotspot (tethering).

Answer (score 0):

Every time I run into this problem it is almost always caused by calling more than one splashscreen for the same page or the splashscreen not being 320x460 pixels (exactly). This should do the trick:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/splash-iphone.jpg" />
```

But before calling the splashscreen, you should include these three lines of code as well:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right, this code must be in  section and the image must be 320x460 pixels, the reason why it is not working is the picture MUST be a small file like 20KB or 25KB or less.
I had the same problem, but when i reduce the file that begin to work.

cheers